# Altering c# delete function in mvc3 for safety

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, crud, entity-framework-mapping

I have a basic CRUD in a CMS, using EF and it was done using Database first, and the delete function does just that it deletes the record from the database.

The following is the controller code for delete:

```
 public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Database_Table database_table = db.Database_Table.Find(id);
        return View(database_table);
    }


    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {            
        Database_Table database_table = db.Database_Table.Find(id);
        db.Database_Table.Remove(database_table);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Now for safety reasons from the clients point of view, instead of actually deleting the entry from the database table, I just want to alter a value in the database, namely 'Deleted, from 'N' to 'Y' and then I will hide it, then the entries that have a value of 'Y' will not be displayed, via a custom query. If that makes sense. My question is how to I alter this code to not delete, but just alter that one value.

I feel it would look something like:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        Database_Name database_name = db.Database_Name.Find(id);
        db.Entry(database_name).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
            return View(database_table);
    }
```

but am unsure where about to define that its only one value that will be modified, in this instance the 'Deleted' value. And maybe also say it should only return to the view a entries with the value 'N'

Comment: Are you using Entity framework for your data access?

Comment: Yes I am using entity framework, database first.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty with EF, I've retagged it as EF though which will prob get you better results.

Comment: I'd just use your default edit method which was created for you, and set your soft delete field from there. Then you can just remove the delete method from your code totally. Using it, you would just be a .Where(x => x.Delete == "y") on your calling methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I recommend you to move these kind of code to a Method in a Different layer ( you can create a new class to have this method there and call it from your controller action/ Any place you want.

```
Database_Name database_name = db.Database_Name.Find(id);

database_name.Deleted="Y";
db.Database_Name.Attach(database_name);
db.Entry(database_name).State = EntityState.Modified;
try
{        
   db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
    context.SaveChanges();        
}
catch (Exception ex2)
{
    //some error. Log it 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will try to implement it now and see how it works. Your my constant saviour.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a use case for [conditional mapping](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/06/15/using-conditional-mapping-in-entity-framework.aspx). Conditional mapping will filter your deleted items automatically from all queries:

- Your Linq queries
- Eager loading
- Lazy loading

There is no other reliable way to filter soft deleted records from eager loaded and lazy loaded data.

But the conditional mapping has also its drawbacks:

- `Deleted` property cannot be part of the entity because it is already used for conditional mapping (you will never be able to query deleted records with this model)
- The delete operation must be [mapped to stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx) (or custom SQL but that requires manual changes in EDMX) which will perform the soft delete for you because you don't have access to `Deleted` property in code
- To make this fully functional you need to use EDMX because code first doesn't support stored procedure mapping yet